# Linking multiple enum values to a single postgreSQL column

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql

I am trying to make a query which will update a column in my database with integers corresponding to an enum table. I am uncertain if I need to do something in my database to allow this behavior or if I just need to make the right query.

venue_themes

```
id   setting
```

setting_enum

```
id    value
1     beach
2     mall
3     yard
```

My backend is receiving an object containing an id and an array of possible setting values.
For example I might receive `id: 123` and `settings: ['mall', 'yard']`.

I am trying to do `UPDATE venue_themes SET setting = (select id from setting_enum where value= req.body.settings)`

I think I might need to use a `AND` statement here but I am not sure how that would be structured.

Comment: How do you plan to store two ids in one field?

Comment: That's what the question is. To clarify, I need one data cell to point to multiple enum values.

Comment: I would suggest that you create a third table to support a many-to-many relationship.

Comment: How would that third table be connected to my current venue_themes table?

Comment: The third table would have two fields - `venue_theme_id` and `setting_enum_id`. Then the third table would simply contain a separate entry for each distinct setting that's associated with the venue theme.

Comment: @fubar Alright I think I understand now. So to put data into my database I will need to add a row to the new table for each setting.  How would I pull data out? I want to be sure I can get those settings back into an array.